# Login system in PHP wont work correctly

Tags: php, authentication

for some reason my login script in php keeps returning invalid results, I'm using PHPMYADMIN to handle the database and mysqli to connect however whenever I submit the data though a HTML form the values always return false even if the correct username and password combo is working.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cnathanielwcol","","login");
if(! $con){die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());}

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM login");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($row);


if ($row["username"]==$username) {
  echo "Correct Username<br>";
} else {
  echo "Wrong Username<br>";
}


if ($row["password"]==$password) {
  echo "Correct Password<br>";
} else {
  echo "Wrong Password<br>";
}

echo "<br><br>Username Submited Via HTML: <b>" . $username . "</b>";
echo "<br>Password Submited Via HTML: <b>" . $password . "</b>";
?>
```

Comment: you are missing some fundamentals in how to deal with databases, the Internet has a great resources about that, would be useful for you to checkout.

Comment: The mysql_ extension that you've used was ***REMOVED*** from PHP 7.0 so on any server running PHP 7.0 or newer you code will be broken. Also passwords should ***NEVER*** be stored in plain text form. have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php for into about PHP's functions for dealing with the hashing of passwords

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cnathanielwcol","FKxIHHoWWtd4Q","login");
```

With

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","cnathanielwcol","FKxIHHoWWtd4Q","login");
```

Your are trying to fetch the data with `mysqli` and your database connection is established by `mysql`

your full code:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","cnathanielwcol","","login") or die('connection is not establised'.mysqli_error($con));

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
$rowCheck=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rowCheck>0) {
    // fetch all data
    //start session
    echo "you are logged in ";
}
else{
    echo 'username or password did not match';
}
```

Use hash password.your code is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you need to select a single row, not all the rows in your table, you'd do that by specifying a `WHERE` clause, currently, you are trying to compare an array of values to a string which should be throwing an error if error reporting is enabled.

**Secondly**, you are mixing to different APIs, `mysql_*` is not `mysqli_*`.

**Thirdly**, it doesn't seems as though you are [hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) your passwords, please, do so.

**Fourthly**, make use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), it seems as though you are still learning so it would be best to start using them now.

**Reading Material**

[OWASP's Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

[OWASP's PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Thank you!, I'm a little stuck using the WHERE clause, could you give me an example or set it up using my script?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is deprecated from new version of PHP use

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","cnathanielwcol","FKxIHHoWWtd4Q","login");
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some clarification around the versions of MySQL, PHP that you refer to, along with version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use mysqli_* please? You might be having a problem with your html form maybe